# matplotlib pgf savefig(pdf) fails

Tags: matplotlib, pgf

On a modern texlive installation on fedora 20, using pgf backend fails in savefig ('blah.pdf').

Example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use("pgf")
pgf_with_rc_fonts = {
    "font.family": "serif",
    "font.serif": [],                   # use latex default serif font
    "font.sans-serif": ["DejaVu Sans"], # use a specific sans-serif font
}
mpl.rcParams.update(pgf_with_rc_fonts)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(4.5,2.5))
plt.plot(range(5))
plt.text(0.5, 3., "serif")
plt.text(0.5, 2., "monospace", family="monospace")
plt.text(2.5, 2., "sans-serif", family="sans-serif")
plt.text(2.5, 1., "comic sans", family="Comic Sans MS")
plt.xlabel(u"µ is not $\\mu$")
plt.tight_layout(.5)
```

trace back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testpgf.py", line 20, in <module>
    plt.tight_layout(.5)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 1255, in tight_layout
    fig.tight_layout(pad=pad, h_pad=h_pad, w_pad=w_pad, rect=rect)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1600, in tight_layout
    renderer = get_renderer(self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.py", line 222, in get_renderer
    renderer = canvas.get_renderer()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pgf.py", line 925, in get_renderer
    return RendererPgf(self.figure, None, dummy=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pgf.py", line 409, in __init__
    self.latexManager = LatexManagerFactory.get_latex_manager()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pgf.py", line 223, in get_latex_manager
    new_inst = LatexManager()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pgf.py", line 305, in __init__
    cwd=self.tmpdir)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: The error seems to be that you do not have latex installed.

Answer (score 1):

OK, problem is that according to http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/pgf.html
the default tex processor is xelatex, which was not installed.  Either
1) sudo yum install texlive-xetex-bin
or
2) set pgf to use some other latex processor:

```
pgf_with_pdflatex = {
    "pgf.texsystem": "lualatex",
    "pgf.preamble": [
        r'\usepackage{amsmath}',
        r'\usepackage[scientific-notation=true]{siunitx}',
    ##      r"\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}",
    ##      r"\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}",
        ]
}
mpl.rcParams.update(pgf_with_pdflatex)
```